# Changing background by separate ID group

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help to do a little thing...

I have two groups of "**A**" tag, the first with "**me**" ID and the second with "**them**" ID. When I click one of "**me**" or "**them**" group, the background of the clicked object change:

```
<a id="me" onclick="me();">text</a>
<a id="me" onclick="me();">text</a>
<a id="me" onclick="me();">text</a>

<a id="them" onclick="them();">text</a>
<a id="them" onclick="them();">text</a>
<a id="them" onclick="them();">text</a>
<script>
    function me(){
        document.getElementById('me').style.backgroundColor='#000000';
    }
    function them(){
        document.getElementById('them').style.backgroundColor='#000000';
    }
</script>
```

I'm not able to change the background of clicked **A** and restore the last clicked **A** independently of ID object...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one element with a given ID.

In your case, you should use a class. For example :

```
<a class="me" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<a class="me" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<a class="me" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<a class="them" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<a class="them" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<a class="them" onclick="similar();">text</a>
<script>
  function similar(){
     var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(this.className);
     for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elems[i].style.backgroundColor='#000000';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: and if i use different IDs like: me1 me2 me3 etc..??

Comment: Then you can, but your code would only change one element's background.

Comment: solved with:
<a onclick="this()">text</a>
<script>
function this(){
var changeDiv;
if(changedDiv){ changedDiv.className=changedDiv.className.replace(' selected',' ') }
theNode.className += " selected";
changedDiv=theNode;
}
</script>